# Print Contents of a DIV stylesheet not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

Cant get the stylesheet to work on the printed document.  It works on the popup window but not when printed.  So when the window on the screen pops up it has the proper styling but when the print dialog is used the print the contents of the window it does not take the styling from the stylesheet just default styles.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-  1.3.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
    }

function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
This will be printed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.    
Pellentesque a quam at nibh adipiscing interdum. Nulla vitae accumsan ante. 
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')">Printout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design your print page.It will not work with your style sheet.You need to write inline style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem and finally solved that this is code :

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
This will be printed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.    
Pellentesque a quam at nibh adipiscing interdum. Nulla vitae accumsan ante. 
</div>
    <a onClick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" class="btn btn-default btn-icon icon-left hidden-print pull-left">
        My Div
        <i class="entypo-print"></i>
    </a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
    }

    function Popup(data)
    {
        var myWindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        myWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        myWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        myWindow.print();
        myWindow.close();

        return true;
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Print pages are usually used inside email as well. Based on what I experienced, you should write all your stylesheet codes within the code (inline).